# How to override plugin properties from pom?

Tags: maven, plugins, properties, overriding

In the plugin pom, there is a property defined as follows:

```
<project 
    ...
    <properties>
        <jruby.version>1.6.8</jruby.version>
    </properties>
```

I would like to override that property in my project's pom (define it to "1.7.0").

Some extra information that might be useful:

- In the plugin's pom, this property is used to:

  - a) specify a dependency version (I know how to override this - see http://blog.sonatype.com/2008/04/how-to-override-a-plugins-dependency-in-maven/
  - b) specify a configuration in a plugin's goal (don't know how to override this)

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Re b) according to [POM Reference, Plugins](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) try:

```
<plugin>
  ...
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>...</id>  
      <goals>
        <goal>...</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>...</phase>
      <configuration>
        <properties>
          <jruby.version>1.7.0</jruby.version>
        </properties>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  ...
</plugin>
```

Comment: Nope, this won't work because the properties I need to overwrite are user-defined properties ([link]http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html#resource-filtering-sect-user-defined) and the approach you're suggesting is for properties that the plugin Mojo may expect (these are getters and setters in the Java Mojo bean)